# How to measure the sparsity of dots on a line?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, algebraic-geometry

I am not sure whether there exists any method to measure the sparsity of dots on a line.

This is what I think that sparsity (after linear mapping) is supposed to be:

1. $0 < SPARSITY([s, t\ , ..., \ u, v]) \leq 1 \ \ \ \ \text{if} \ \ 0 = s \leq t \leq \ ...\  \leq u \leq v = 1$
2. $0 < SPARSITY\left(\left[ 0, \dfrac{1}{5}, \dfrac{2}{5}, \dfrac{1}{2}, 1\right]\right) < SPARSITY\left(\left[ 0, \dfrac{1}{4}, \dfrac{2}{4}, \dfrac{3}{4}, 1 \right]\right) = 1$

If all the dots are evenly spaced, then the sparsity is $1$without any problem, but I am curious how to give out an expression to evaluate the sparsity of dots on a line? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a really vague question: what you want can be achieved in a lot of different ways. This one has just come to mind:

$$
SPARSITY([0=a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}, a_n=1])=
{1\over1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_k-k/n)^2}
$$

Could that work for you?

Comment: This meets the requirement, but I am not sure whether this is the best solution. Thanks for your help, and I'll do more research on this stuff. ;-)